# Jquery draggable: how to make compononent smaller while dragging?

Tags: jquery, resize, draggable

I have a dragable image to be dropped on a smaller dropable.
I would like to make the image smaller while dragging to visually fit in the targer,
so on the start event I use:

```
start: function() { 
     $("#primage").css({'width':'80px','height':'auto'});...
```

The problem is that when the dragging starts, the cursor is positioned according to the initial image size, so it is out of the now smaller image (higher and to the left). 
I tried setting the cursorat left option further to the right   to accommodate  the change of width but then the over event of the dropable does not fire when the image is over it but further to the right.
How can I set the cursorat according to the new image size or can you suggest another solution?

Comment: Could you show some minimal example code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Maybe you could add position:relative; top:..; left:..; to the dragged thing to move it under the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could position the image at the cursor location instead of trying to position the cursor itself.